# Passing DropDownListFor through Model Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, dropdownlistfor

I can't seem to crack how to pass a `DropDownListFor` through my Model class, 
I've only been able to figure how to do it just using a standard `dropdownlist`. I'm gonna post how I've done it in the past

```
 public class NewLogin
{
    public string UserRole     { get; set; }
    public int RoleID          { get; set; }
    public SelectList RoleList { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how I'm getting the data for my DDL in my LinQ statement, Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
    public NewLogin PopUserDDL()
    { 
        NewLogin nl = new NewLogin();
        using (database db = new database())
        {                                     
            nl.RoleList = new SelectList(GetRolesForDDL(), "RoleID", "UserRole");                
        }
        return nl;      
    }   
    public  List<NewLogin> GetRolesForDDL()
    {
        using (database db = new database())
        {
            return (from r in db.UserRole                       
                    select new NewLogin
                    {
                        UserRole = r.Role,
                        RoleID = r.RoleID
                    }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I'm calling it in my view like
`@Html.DropDownList("lstRoles",(SelectList)ViewBag.RolesList)`

And I'm passing it like

```
  public ActionResult Index(NewLogin newlogin, int lstRoles)
    {
    }
```

I've tried dropdown for and trying to get it passed straight through the model but haven't had any luck.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using a viewModel at all?

Comment: `but haven't had any luck` - this kind of expression **doesn't help much in making your question clear so that people can help**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.DropDownListFor` requires that your view is strongly typed. If your model is of type `NewLogin`, you can write it like this :

```
@model MyNamespace.NewLogin

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleID, Model.RoleList)
```

In your post action, you get selected `RoleID` in your `NewLogin` parameter.

Edit : in your controller, your calling action can be this :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    NewLogin newLogin = PopUserDDL();
    return View(newLogin);
}
```

`Model` property of your view will contain the data you need. It is a better solution than `ViewBags`.

Comment: Ok, I've gotten the RoleID now, if I wanted to get the text value as well as RoleID how could I select that?

Comment: When you select an item in a drop down list, you get a value associated with it. In your case it's an ID, if you also want text value you'll probably have to search for it in `RoleList`, using the ID you got. Do you need it in your view or in your post action ?

Comment: no I don't, but I was thinking if  I needed to do something like that in the future, but if I wanted too I could use JQuery to get it. Right now when I pass it in I'm get this....Role id = "13" then UserRole and RoleList are both null would this be working as intended? Originally I was thinking theres gotta be a way  where i could have RoleID and UserList as sub properties of RoleList so when accessing them I could do NewLogin.RoleList.RoleID, nitpicking I know but I'm just curious.

Comment: +1 for "It is a better solution than ViewBag". Personally, I wish Microsoft would just remove ViewBag altogether. It's horrible and horribly overused.